# How to add month and year in pdf batch file using powerscript?

Tags: powershell, file-rename, batch-rename

I have 500 files that needed to be renamed from: `surname_dtr.pdf` to `surname_YYYYMMdtr.pdf` where `YYYY` is the current year, and `MM` is the previous month. I have known that this is possible using script. I do not have a background in writing a script that's why I am looking for an answer here, but no avail.

Comment: While your problem is well-defined, the down-votes likely stem from the fact that your question does not demonstrate any effort to solve it yourself (saying that you don't have a background in scripting isn't considered a mitigating circumstance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
# Get the previous month's string representation in the desired format.
$timestampStr = (Get-Date -Day 1).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMM')

# Rename all files of interest in the current dir., 
# using a delay-bind script block.
Get-ChildItem -Filter *_dtr.pdf |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + $timestampStr + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

See also:

- [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date)
- [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item)
- [delay-bind script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters)